# monitor php script executions

Tags: php

I recently started with php and I have a script that works with a database. This script is triggered from an iOS app.

I can monitor the iOS apps behavior, but I am not sure how to monitor execution of the php script. Is there some test environment I could setup or another tool that is used for this?

I want to set breakpoints in the php script so I can see how it reacts to the requests from the iOS application.

EDIT: How are people testing php otherwise? Does the script get refactored after testing to allow actual usage on a server? I guess I am after some kind of tool that attaches to a script that is live on a server.

Comment: Try [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: ya, xdebug has remote debugging ability. installing it and getting it all set up was a real pita last time i did it. I would try to take the low road and just log debug messages to a file lol.

Answer (score 0):

I use phpEd by NuSphere, but you have to execute the script from the editor/debugger.  If you want all the requests made to the script, you'll need to add a code to write to a log file at various points in the script.  (If anyone has heard of something other than that, I'd LOVE to know about it!)